# Image replacement with font-size: 0

Tags: html, css

I really like to kill text for image replacement with `font: 0/0 a`, but as I know it does not really work everywhere.

So do we still need

```
text-indent: -9999px;
overflow: hidden;
```

for this?

Comment: There are so many ways to hide text... `display:none` is the most thorough, but you also have `visibility:hidden`, `opacity:0`, `position:absolute; right:100%`, `height:0; overflow:hidden` etc. In some circumstances, even changing the `z-index` works. So it depends on your situation and your needs.

Comment: Oh, a text indent in pixels is not a good idea, because at one point in the future, the users' screens are going to be larger than 9999 pixels. `-100%` is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mr Lister commented, there are many, *many* different ways to do image replacement.  There are up and down sides to all of them.  There is one technique where the only real down side is that it requires support for psuedo elements (so IE8+).

- No extra markup
- Works with images disabled
- Works with transparent images
- Does not require adjustment of font-size
- Does not require messing with positioning

http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-image-replacement-with-pseudo-elements/

```
.nir {
   height:100px; /* height of replacement image */
   width:400px; /* width of replacement image */
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.nir:before {
   content:url(image.gif);
   display:inline-block;
   font-size:0;
   line-height:0;
}
```

Comment: Sure, pseudo-elements are good. But there are times when I don't want to use, and really there is no need.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

You can replace the image with a background and use padding to move the actual image away. This is just one of many solutions.

http://jsfiddle.net/gj5F2/2/

**Css**

```
div
{
    width: 550px;
    height: 190px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img2
{
    background: url('http://www.google.com/logos/2013/ghana_independence_day_2013-1202005-hp.jpg') no-repeat left top;
    padding-left: 550px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="img1" src="http://www.google.dk/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width="550" height="190" />

<div>
    <img class="img2" src="http://www.google.dk/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width="550" height="190" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am asking about image replacement, not text hiding.